# Are all stickers on a sheet used or do you sometimes have spare? Dino HQ set 5887

Tags: sets, stickers

I built Dino set 5887 recently, but the sticker sheet contains one extra sticker: one of the 'D' things, the pentagram one. One went on one of the walls, the other two round 'D's went on the chopper. I went through the instruction manuals 17 times to find it but for the life of me, I cannot.

Is it correct that I have one spare sticker on this one?

Answer (score 3):

You occasionally get "extra" stickers, especially in the Police sub-theme of City, where the sheets have both "Police" and "Polizei" variations:

[image: Police Plane Sticker Sheet]
[Police Plane Sticker Sheet on Peeron](http://www.peeron.com/inv/parts/61974)

Answer (score 2):

That's definitely an extra. I checked the instructions to confirm this.

I can't comment on how common spare stickers are, as I don't personally apply the stickers in general.

Answer (score 1):

Although I have never seen an extra sticker in another set, you are correct in that this set does have an extra "D" pentagon sticker.